# filter JSON array javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I'm just thinking about how to simplify my filter code below. It filters out all JSON strings from a JSON array that contain searched values in one of three particular JSON string keys. My Visual Studio is smiling at me that if I'm kidding with my code complexity :D So I'm just curious if there is any different way of how to modify my code snippet to make it more effective.

```js
return _.filter(obj, item => {
    return _.every(filterParams, keyword => {
        return _.some(item, value => {
            return _.isString(value) && (
              item.names1.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase()) ||
              item.names2.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase()) ||
              item.names3.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase()))
        })
    });
  });
```

Here is a data example:

```
export const data = [{
  "HELP": "ageGroup1",
  "Name": "ga1",
  "EN": "ageGroup1",
  "CZ": "N",
  "names1": "AgeGroup",
  "names2": "Element",
  "names3": "N"
}, {
  "HELP": "Level2",
  "Name": "L2",
  "EN": "aggregationGroup",
  "CZ": "N",
  "names1": "AggregationLevel",
  "names2": "ElementLevel",
  "names3": "N"
}]
```

Comment: This question seems like it would be a perfect candidate for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to refactor your code. I don't think you need to use lodash. This might not be the exact refactoring of your code, but hopefully this should give you an idea of what it could look like.

```
let keywordCompare = (keyword) => keyword.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase());
let filteredNames = obj.filter(
obj => keywordCompare(obj.name1) || keywordCompare(obj.name2) || keywordCompare(obj.name3)
);
```

Seems a lot cleaner in my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

You could take the keys of the object and iterate with `some` for short circuit if found.

```
return _.filter(obj, item => {
    return _.every(filterParams, keyword => {
        return _.some(item, value => {
            return _.isString(value) && ['names1', 'names2', 'names3']
                .some(n => item[n].toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase()))
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: Grazie Nina, looks great!

Comment: What about type checking? (I mean `names1`)

Comment: This doesn't look "simplified" at all.

Comment: whicout knowing the data what what to loop up, it's hard to simplifiy something more than the jard coded properties which checks the same ...